# join the results of two query on each others with Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have 2 models, i simplify them for the example:

```
class CustomerOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    isPaid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and

```
class EventParticipant(models.Model):
    customerOrder = models.ForeignKey(CustomerOrder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What i need to do is to display in a table every participants for an event but link the order to the participant so i can display the isPaid status for each participant.

I think its similar to a join on SQL.

So i tried something like:

```
participants = EventParticipant.objects.filter(event=event_pk).select_related('customerOrder')
```

but when i try to access it like

```
participants.cusomerOrder
```

i get: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'customerOrder'

so i guess is missunderstand something.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`participants`** is an **`EventParticipant` QuerySet**, whcih is an ***iterable***, So you need to iterate over it

```
for participant in participants:
    print(participant.customerOrder.isPaid)
```